# Sort function in c++ makes all elements in integer array 0

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to sort an integer array in c++ using the `STL` `sort()` function but when I'm trying to sort, it makes all the elements of array `0`.

This is my code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

const int maxn = 1e5+10;

long long int v[maxn], u[maxn];

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        cin >> v[i];
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        u[i] = v[i];
        cout << u[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n';
    int x = sizeof(u) / sizeof(u[1]);
    sort(u, u + x);
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        cout << u[i] << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this sample input and output:

input:

```
5
3 5 4 1 2
```

output:

```
3 5 4 1 2
0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: `int v[n+1], u[n+1];` Ask yourself what the value of `n` is when that *specific* line is encountered? Hint: those don't magically resize when you later change `n`. So, if your answer is "I dunno what `n` is" you're in the same boat as your program; it doesn't either. Second, avoid using VLAs (variable length arrays) in C++ in the first place; they're non-standard. Use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Get used to zero-based indexing. [Dijkstra](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) was right.

Comment: @WhozCraig Can you check it again? I deleted that line. Output is the same!

Comment: @molbdnilo Made the array zero indexed and still the same result...! BTW I need it to be  one-based indexed.

Comment: Since n is 5, the array u consists of the five values you entered and the rest are all zero. You then sort the entire thing, so all the zero values participate in the sort and end up at the front. (Instead of 3 5 4 1 2, try some negative numbers.)

Comment: `maxn` is 10^5 and most of the global variables are initialized to 0. That's why when you run `sort()`, all zeros will come first. If you are not sure of the size of array, use `std::vector`.

Comment: *"I need it to be one-based indexed."* -no, you really don't. And if you did (which you don't), you need to adjust the arguments to `sort` regardless, which should be `sort(u+1, u+n+1);`

Comment: @Aidin *I need it to be one-based indexed.* -- No.  Trying to fake one-based arrays leaves you open for off-by-one bugs.  Those bugs can occur at the end of the array, where you're accessing an out-of-bounds element, or at the beginning of the array where you are accessing element 0 (when you shouldn't have accessed it).  Then you get into real trouble if you *forget* that your arrays are 1-based, and some of your code starts to assume 0-based.  Too much trouble -- just start indexing from 0 all the time, every time.

Comment: @RaymondChen WOW! Thanks! I haven't noticed that! So, is there any way to sort the first n elements of the array?

Comment: Yes, use `n` instead of `x` (and add the `1`s you insist on having)

Comment: Look closely at the two lines viz., `    int x = sizeof(u) / sizeof(u[1]);
    sort(u, u + x);` What is the value of `x` and how many elements do you think `sort` is processing?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need `u` array? You could just use `v`. Use `std::vector` if you are unsure of the size.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v(n);            // for 1-based indexing, replace n with n + 1
    vector<int> u(n);            // for 1-based indexing, replace n with n + 1
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // for 1-based indexing, replace with i = 1; i <= n
        cin >> v[i];
        u[i] = v[i];
        cout << u[i] << " ";
    } cout << "\n";

    sort(v.begin(), v.end());    // for 1-based indexing, replace v.begin() with v.begin() + 1

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // for 1-based indexing, replace with i = 1; i <= n
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I need it because the question needs it.

Comment: Edited my answer. Although, I am not sure why the question would ask to waste an entire array. What is the exact question statement? Please edit your question and include the exact question statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think for loop must be  `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)` not `for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)` in both the cases.

Answer (score -1):

when you created `v(1e5+10)` and `u(1e5+10)` and by default they were initialized with zeroes. There are 100000 variable of type `int` initialized with zeros.
when you `cin>> 35412`, it got allocated at v[0]=3 v[1]=5 v[2]=4 v[3]=1 v[4]=2 and remaining v[5]=0 v[6]=0 v[7]=0.....v[100000]=0.
u copied v->u, u[0]=3 u[1]=5 u[2]=4 u[3]=1 u[4]=2 and remaining u[5]=0 u[6]=0 u[7]=0.....u[100000]=0.
`int x = sizeof(u) / sizeof(u[1]);` size of u is 100000
when you sorted u using  `sort(u, u + x)`, u points to u[0] and u+x points to last element that is u[100000]=0.
so, you are sorting {3,5,4,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0.....,0} and after sorting it will become
{0,0,0,0,0,0.....,1,2,3,4,5}.
and you print only the first 5 element of the sorted array that is `0000`.